# BatchFile Search specific file EXTENSION and move it to a specific FOLDER

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Here is my folder structure, and I want to run a batch file to search through all those parents folder and move existing .dat file to the subfolder x

I need someone to help me with that :) thanks alot

```
- NETWORK FOLDER ( WHERE I WANT THE BACTCHFILE TO BE LAUNCHED  )

    - PARENT FOLDER 1
         -subfolder 1
         -subfolder 2
         -subfolder 3
         -subfolder x
        files_name.dat

    - PARENT FOLDER 2
         -subfolder 1
         -subfolder 2
         -subfolder 3
         -subfolder x
        files_name.dat

    - PARENT FOLDER 3
         -subfolder 1
         -subfolder 2
         -subfolder 3
         -subfolder x
        files_name.dat
```

I'm a beginner in coding for now I only have pretty basic code. This code work only if I put the .bat in the PARENT FOLDER. I've tried to run it in the Network Folder, and it not working.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.dat') do (
  move  /y "%%a" subfolder x\
)
```

Comment: Take a look at robocopy.  I believe that it can do this out of the box if you read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like this. It copies dat files to a folder called DatFiles and renames possible duplicate names in the subfolders.

```
@echo off
chcp 1252> Nul

set Source=\\Lenovo\Test\Source
set Destination=\\Lenovo\Test\Source\DatFiles
set Type=.dat

If /i not exist "%Destination%" md "%Destination%"

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s "%Source%\*%Type%" ^| find /i /v "%Destination%\"') do (
if /i exist "%Destination%\%%~nxa" (
set "File=%%~na"
set "Extension=%%~xa"
set "FullPath=%%a"
call :Rename
)
if /i not exist "%Destination%\%%~nxa" move "%%a" "%Destination%"
)
exit

:Rename
for /l %%b in (1,1,100) do if /i not exist "%Destination%\%File%(%%b)%Extension%" move "%FullPath%" "%Destination%\%File%(%%b)%Extension%" & goto :EOF
goto :EOF
```

[image]